# Dynamically profile the name of the class called for reflection site in java

Tags: java, reflection, runtime, profile

Is there any possible way to know the name of the class called for each reflection site in runtime Java?

For a more concrete example, in java code we may have

```
   String className = readfromXMlConfig; //read from xml config file
　　class c = Class.forName(className);

　　ExampleInterface factory = (ExampleInterface)c.newInstance();
```

The className is not clear in static analysis, however the information can be known in runtime. I would like to record the resolved names of the classes dynamically for future analysis.

I have investigated state-of-the-art static analysis tools (e.g., Soot) for handling reflection, and found this is what they commonly do. Unfortunately I cannot use Soot for version-compatibility reason and have to implement the dynamic part myself.

Comment: I don't understand. You want to inspect every call that is made from classes in the `java.lang.reflection` package (and/or `java.lang.Class`)?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I misunderstood newInstance() method, and have edited the problem.

Comment: AOP might be an option but I'm not sure if Aspect J can advise bootstrap classes like `java.lang.Class`.

Comment: Your question still is incomprehensible. You have a `Class` object you’re calling `newInstance()` on. The resulting object will have the type represented by this `Class` object. The name of the type is what calling `getName()` on the `Class` object will return. No other type can “be possibly instantiated” by this call. Perhaps, you need to explain what you mean with “to dynamically profile”.

Comment: I edited my question again and hope it is clearer. The question is how to record the resolved classes for reflection in runtime.